# Copying data from one sqlite table into another

Tags: sqlite

(SQlite noob here!)

This seems to be a common question, but none of the solutions I've seen are quite what I'm looking for. The example below is a contrived example of the problem I'm having.

Here's a summary of the problem:

Given: Two tables with differing structure. One table consists of columns with a list of cities, population of the city, and population-related data. The population column of this table starts out as all '0'. The second table consists of columns containing cities and population of that city for SOME of the cities. I want to insert the data from the population column of the second table into the population column of the first table.

For example:

City table:

```
CREATE TABLE [cities] (
    [City] TEXT,
    [Population] INT,
    [U10] REAL,
    [U20] REAL,
    [U30] REAL,
    [U40] REAL,
    [U50] REAL,
    [U60] REAL,
    [U70] REAL,
    [U80] REAL,
    [U90] REAL,
    [O90] REAL
);
```

Population table:

```
CREATE TABLE [pop] (
   [City] TEXT,
   [Population] INT
};
```

I've tried many variations of

```
UPDATE cities SET Population = (SELECT Population FROM pop) WHERE City = (SELECT City FROM pop);
```

without success. Sometimes I get one entry updated (with the wrong value). Other times I get all population values set to the same thing. Surely, I'm overlooking something obvious.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause has to be in the subquery.

```
UPDATE cities
       SET population = (SELECT pop.population
                                FROM pop
                                WHERE pop.city = cities.city);
```

If you only want to update cities for which a row in `pop` exists, additionally add a `WHERE` clause with `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery to the outer statement. Without such a `WHERE` clause the population of cities not existing in `pop` is set to `NULL` possibly overwriting existing non `NULL` values.

```
UPDATE cities
       SET population = (SELECT pop.population
                                FROM pop
                                WHERE pop.city = cities.city)
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM pop
                            WHERE pop.city = cities.city);
```

Comment: Wow! Talk about a fast answer! This seems to do exactly what I need.  Many thanks!